# Solving quadratic equations bug in Mathematica 12.3

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

There seems to be some sort of bug in mathematica, where sometimes it will treat a quadratic equation as a quartic equation. For example:

```
Solve[c + b x + x^2 == 0, x, Assumptions -> b >= 0]
```

will output

```
{{x -> ConditionalExpression[
    Root[-Im[c]^2 + 
        b^2 Re[c] + (b^3 + 4 b Re[c]) #1 + (5 b^2 + 4 Re[c]) #1^2 + 
        8 b #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1] - 
     I \[Sqrt](Re[c] + 
         b Root[-Im[c]^2 + 
             b^2 Re[c] + (b^3 + 4 b Re[c]) #1 + (5 b^2 + 
                4 Re[c]) #1^2 + 8 b #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1] + 
         Root[-Im[c]^2 + 
            b^2 Re[c] + (b^3 + 4 b Re[c]) #1 + (5 b^2 + 
               4 Re[c]) #1^2 + 8 b #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1]^2), 
    Im[c] < 0]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    Root[-Im[c]^2 + 
        b^2 Re[c] + (b^3 + 4 b Re[c]) #1 + (5 b^2 + 4 Re[c]) #1^2 + 
        8 b #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1] + 
     I \[Sqrt](Re[c] + 
         b Root[-Im[c]^2 + 
             b^2 Re[c] + (b^3 + 4 b Re[c]) #1 + (5 b^2 + 
                4 Re[c]) #1^2 + 8 b #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1] + 
         Root[-Im[c]^2 + 
            b^2 Re[c] + (b^3 + 4 b Re[c]) #1 + (5 b^2 + 
               4 Re[c]) #1^2 + 8 b #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1]^2), 
    Im[c] > 0]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    Root[-Im[c]^2 + 
        b^2 Re[c] + (b^3 + 4 b Re[c]) #1 + (5 b^2 + 4 Re[c]) #1^2 + 
        8 b #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 2] - 
     I \[Sqrt](Re[c] + 
         b Root[-Im[c]^2 + 
             b^2 Re[c] + (b^3 + 4 b Re[c]) #1 + (5 b^2 + 
                4 Re[c]) #1^2 + 8 b #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 2] + 
         Root[-Im[c]^2 + 
            b^2 Re[c] + (b^3 + 4 b Re[c]) #1 + (5 b^2 + 
               4 Re[c]) #1^2 + 8 b #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 2]^2), 
    Im[c] > 0]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    Root[-Im[c]^2 + 
        b^2 Re[c] + (b^3 + 4 b Re[c]) #1 + (5 b^2 + 4 Re[c]) #1^2 + 
        8 b #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 2] + 
     I \[Sqrt](Re[c] + 
         b Root[-Im[c]^2 + 
             b^2 Re[c] + (b^3 + 4 b Re[c]) #1 + (5 b^2 + 
                4 Re[c]) #1^2 + 8 b #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 2] + 
         Root[-Im[c]^2 + 
            b^2 Re[c] + (b^3 + 4 b Re[c]) #1 + (5 b^2 + 
               4 Re[c]) #1^2 + 8 b #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 2]^2), 
    Im[c] < 0]}}
```

Any idea of what is going on here?

Comment: Mathematica assumes that all variables other than `b` are complex. If you are only looking for solutions associated with real variables, use `Assuming[b >= 0, Solve[c + b x + x^2 == 0, x, Reals] // Simplify]`

Comment: Well, c is complex, but this should still be solved by the quadratic formula

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag for your own questions. Please see the tag description for an explanation. Please do assist in adding the tag to others' posts (once you have sufficient reputation score to do so).

Comment: This looks like an error to me. It implies that there is only a solution for Im[c] < 0 what is definitely wrong. Please report this to support@wolfram.com and post their answer here.

Comment: @DanielHuber if you look closely they have both cases, they separate Im[c] < 0 from Im[c]> 0. It still looks like a mistake. I have emailed support@wolfram.com. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is effectively solving the system c + b x + x^2 == 0 && b >= 0, where x and c are complex and b is real. This gets converted to a system in 5 real variables {b, Re[c], Im[c], Re[x], Im[x]}. The system is solved using the cylindrical algebraic decomposition algorithm, which yields solutions for Re[x] and Im[x] with inequality conditions on b, Re[c], and Im[c].

Of course a human can easily see that the assumption makes no difference for the solutions of this specific equation. Solve has to add the assumption to the system, because it might make a difference, e.g.

```
In[4]:= Solve[(b-Abs[b]) x^2 + x == 1, x, Assumptions -> b >= 0]                
Out[4]= {{x -> 1}}
```

Comment: Should it not still be considered as bug given it is such an innefficient way to present the result?

Comment: @Filipe Miguel have you reported it to Wolfram Support & have they confirmed it as a bug? If not, then no, do not use the bugs tag.